# Detect grid upon grid in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I have 2 Grids in XAML. One small and one big. How I can detect that, after first move, it upon second? I need smth like coordinates (need to align the first grid to the second grid's border or to other grids in this 'big-grid'). What're methods, properties?

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Parent" Margin="124,340,1042,228">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" ManipulationDelta="Object_ManipulationDelta" x:Name="Figure" ManipulationMode="All">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="-10,30,70,30"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="-10,70,70,-10"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="-50,70,110,-10"/>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Field" Width="500" Height="700">
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10,10,450,650" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF1B1B1B"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="50,10,410,650" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF1B1B1B"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="90,10,370,650" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF1B1B1B"/>
        <!--many rectangles-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I move Grid Figure to Grid Field. In future I may be change rectangle to border.

Comment: Can you post your XAML?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu yes, I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the relative position between Figure and Field, you can use something like that:

```
var transform= Field.TransformToVisual(Figure);
Point relativePosition = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0,0));
```

relativeCoordinate will be the distance between the Top Left of Field and the Top left of Figure

if you want the absolute coordinate of the Grid you can do this:

```
 var transform= this.TransformToVisual(Figure);
 Point absolutePositionFigureGrid = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0,0));
```

Comment: Execuse me, but if I rotate Figure (and when I rotate I change its CenterX/Y) it doesnt work until I return it to its original position. May be you can help me again?